# a highly sophisticated and persistent DDoS attack

Tags: ddos

i had ddos attack

i used wireshark to analyzes packets on entery point (ethernet interface) i found packets incoming on:

mac protocol=800 (ip)
protocol=17 (udp)
src-address=(diffirent ips from the world for each packet)
src-port=(diffirent ports for each packet)
dst-address=(diffirent ips for each packet)
dst-port=(diffirent ports for each packet)

i have implemented a filter to drop all incoming traffic at my network's entry point (drop everything), 
but the DDoS attack is still getting through 
and i receiving UDP packets with different source and destination IP addresses for each packet, 
then try to change mac address for entry interface (ethernet), and not worked , 
when you turn in interface the attack start without setup any thing.

note 1: there ars only (rx packet) without (tx packet) on entry point
note 2: my isp have (switch network) to the internet (there is no servers or routers or any thing just switches) after that the isp give us global ip (we can reatch to this ip from all internet) .

what's type this ddos ?
and depens on what ?

if i have no config on entry point - no ip and nothing 
only the mac-address and connection to isp 
how is rx packet come without tx 
i had wireshark sniff file when attacks on if needed

any help
please..
[image]

network info ( and logs show nothing ) just read traffic on interface
[image]

Comment: It would help if you can give us a good network description or diagram, the network device models (especially the firewall), the network device configurations, and any logs, debugs, etc.

Comment: ok i uploaded a piture to network models and diagram
and i have some thing best 
i will give you login to the device (mikrotik routeerboard 5009)  when attacked and you can make pacage sniffer or torch and you can take any info you want from device 

after end please share info for type and protection to help anyone have same proplem  

--please  send email to me at : a.a.rgb.aar@gmail.com

-- or facebook : cardlife2

--or telegram : https://t.me/cardlife

to talk to you and give you need admin login info ....

Comment: The firewall should be at the entrance to your network. The firewall protects your network, but you cannot stop a DDoS attack since it uses the bandwidth before you even see the traffic. Your carrier needs to stop it upstream from you. You set up something like RTBH with the ISP.

Comment: best answer ... thankyou  --- you are wonderfull person ,hope best days for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i have implemented a filter to drop all incoming UDP traffic at my network's entry point, but the DDoS attack is still getting through

It's a firewall's *default* to drop all ingress traffic unless it a) matches an outbound session or b) is destination NATed/port forwarded to a private host.

That random traffic that you describe cannot get through your firewall unless there's something severely wrong with the setup. If you can't handle it you should hire an experienced consultant.

It's quite possible though that the amount of traffic you receive oversaturates your Internet link. In that case you'd need to ask your ISP for help, so they filter the traffic on their perimeter. There are a few methods to cope with DDoS but your ISP needs to be able to set them up. You should talk to them.

Comment: thankyou ,
i want to know , 
what's type this ddos ? 
and depens on what ?

if i have no config on entry point - no ip and nothing 
only the mac-address and connection to isp 
how is rx packet come without tx?
can you give me some information please..

my isp cannot do any thing because this type of attack is reatch to all isp network and stop everything>

also i had wireshark sniff file when attacks on if needed.

thankyou becoause of your answer i change the post to have more info

Comment: You're not providing sufficient information in your question to decide which type of DDoS that might be - a decent packet capture might help though. Ingress traffic without outbound sessions is the nature of many DDoS types. If your ISP is bust then there's nothing you can do except look out for another ISP.

Comment: ok..
thankyou agine 

if you have free time look to the picture that i added in the post .
it's fore one of the packets of attack.
i hope if you know something about type of attack and if you know any way to stop it. and this will help the other people to protect him selvs..

thank you so much ...

Comment: That screenshot shows very little, nowhere near enough to say anything. It's all about finding a pattern (if there is one) to forge rules to repel the attack. If it's not only about bandwidth you *must* secure or replace your firewall first.